# Weighted average in R based on a few rows

Tags: r

I have a data frame like...

```
date, name, area, value
01/01/15, brian, 20, 3
01/01/15, james, 30, 6
02/01/15, brian, 30, 4
02/01/15, james, 30, 5
```

And I'd like to calculate a weighted average from this on a day-by-day basis.

In this simplified example, I would want `(20*3+30*6)/(20+30) = 01/01/15 weighted average` and `(30*4+30*5)/(30+30) = 02/01/15 weighted average` etc.

The number of rows that contribute to a day's weighted average are not known a priori and can be dynamic. There are several values that I would want the weighted average for, but of course if I have a single working example it should be easy to generalise

Thank you!

Comment: Should the weighted average be in the same dataframe or in a new one?

Comment: Dont mind where it is output to. My ultimate output would be `date, a few weighted averages , , , ` - so the original values are not necessary to that extent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[,.(waverage=sum(area*value)/sum(area)), date]

#       date waverage
#1: 01/01/15      4.8
#2: 02/01/15      4.5
```

Or using `weighted.mean`:

```
setDT(df)[,.(waverage=weighted.mean(value,area)), date]
```

Base `R` you can use `ave`:

```
with(df, ave(value*area, date, FUN=sum)/ave(area, date, FUN=sum))
```

Comment: I'm ideally trying to do this in `baser` only

Comment: true that you will not have to install a package but the syntax is light on the other hand!

Comment: There are also operational reasons - this isnt just an exploratory analysis sadly!

Comment: I added a base R solution with ave, even if it's less efficient than data.table

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll have a look into it once I have my data set up correctly.

Comment: I'm getting an error `unique() only applies to vectors` ?

Comment: I do not use unique() in my code...there is only a dataframe df, the one you provided.

Comment: I appreciate that, but I've taken your code and that's the error I get. I load the data from my CSV,
`values<-data.frame(read.csv(file='blah.csv',fileEncoding='latin1'))

weighted<-with(values,ave(x*Area, date, FUN=sum)/(ave(Area,date,FUN=sum))`

and I get the error message

Comment: Okay, I've just re-created my minimum example above (the data structure I'm actually using is a little more complex) - it seems to work fine in that instance. Will investigate.

Comment: I fixed my bug. I was using `Area` and `Date` in the first ave, but then `area` and `date` in the second ave. One thing I dont like about R, it should cry hard when I try to use variables that dont exist.

Comment: :) yes you need to be cautious about the variable spelling!

Comment: This isnt working for me. It works if I take a simplified example with 3 rows for 1 date, but when I scale it up to a 30 year history, it breaks. And I have no idea why... The date column is YYYY-mm-dd, and the formatting seems to be read fine, so I dont think it's doing anything redundant from that side. Argh!

Comment: You really can't use data.table??

Comment: I've done everything in `baser` so far so I somewhat loathe to deviate from that. Also, we dont know what technology we will use yet for the distributed computing so I am not 100% sure how that will deal with library imports

Comment: What is the use of Date at the end?

Comment: to group by date.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, e.g.

```
stack(lapply(split(df[, 3:4], df$date), function(df) with(df, weighted.mean(x = value, w = area))))
# values      ind
# 1    4.8 01/01/15
# 2    4.5 02/01/15
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a go in a sec and see if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `by` function

```
by(df, df$date, function(grp) weighted.mean(grp$value, grp$area), simplify=FALSE)
```

This returns a list (`simplify=FALSE`) with the dates as the names and weighted means as the values.

You can then use `unlist` if you want a named vector or `data.frame(dates=names(var), means=unlist(var))` for a dataframe.